# Removing A Group Of Controls From a Parent (Winforms Powershell)

Tags: powershell, winforms

I have a script I wrote in powershell that creates checkboxes for each user in C:\users

[image: Checkboxes]

I want to remove them from the form as a group but when I use this:

```
Foreach ($control in $sourceTab.Controls) {
        if ($control.GetType().ToString() -eq "System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox"){
            $sourceTab.Controls.Remove($control)
        }
    }
```

It only removes one of the Checkboxes, Not all of them.

[image: LastCheckBox]

If I run the code again, it removes the 2nd checkbox as if its only removing them one by one

I have tried multiple different ways of removing them but for some reason, once it removes one control, it stops the loop. Which I dont understand.

Comment: Use a `for` loop and `RemoveAt(0)`. Or a backwards `for` loop.

Comment: @Jimi Im a noob when it comes to winforms, can you give me an example?

Comment: If your `$sourceTab` contains just those Controls, you can simply clear the collection: `$sourceTab.Controls.Clear()` -- Otherwise, use, e.g., a backwards `for` loop: `for (($i = $sourceTab.Controls.Count - 1); $i -ge 0; $i--) { if ($sourceTab.Controls[$i] -is [System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox]) { $sourceTab.Controls.RemoveAt($i) }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Indexes = @()
    Foreach ($control in $sourceTab.Controls) {
        if ($control.GetType().ToString() -eq "System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox"){
            $Indexes += $control.TabIndex
        }
    }
    Foreach ($index in $indexes | Sort-Object -Descending){
        $sourceTab.Controls.RemoveAt($index)
    }
```

Thank you @jimi for suggesting this fix, it worked!